# Preloaded Fusion Table that is specific to each user

Tags: excel, user-input, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

So here is the dilema and I am sure it is a simple solution.  I am using App Inventor 2.

I would like to use Fusion and have it so that it automatically creates for example 4 preloaded/precreated tables to make things easy for the user.

table1, table2, table3, table4.

Then these tables would be customizable per each user that downloads the app.  They would have their own private fusion tables with their own private info they created.

So my aim is that if someone downloaded the app, they wouldn't have to create a fusion table or know anything about coding, it would automatically populate on their google account and be retrievable on it.

Also is there a way to easily obtain that info later via CSV(comma separated value) with Excel from their web browser on their PC from online with a simple link?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In **App Inventor** there are the built-in `fusiontable controls`, but these only can access your tables (the tables of the developer account).

To be able to access the Google Drive of the user and create and access fusiontables there, you can use the `web` component and OAuth following the [**Google Fusion Tables API**](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using). The user needs to authorize your app to be able to create and access the fusiontables on first run of the app.

See an example how to do it [here](https://puravidaapps.com/fusionDB.php).

The users can obtain that info later with a simple link, they just have to set the sharing permissions of the fusiontables to "anyone with link".